# Database( Oracle ) health checks

Tags: database, oracle, metrics, hikaricp

We use many distributed components ( ElasticSearch, Oracle, Redis, etc) in our stack. Sometimes we run into issues where some components are not initialized properly or are not up fully which wastes application testing time. I am writing a simple full-stack health checker in our client application to determine things like
a) Connection status with each component
b) possibly slightly deeper metrics 
I know I can get some of the information from ES/Redis client's JMX api.

However, for Oracle apart from the usual "Select 1 from dual", how can I get other metrics like:

- RAC related statistics ( internode pings, cache statistics )
- CPU load
- RAM usage
- Swap space usage

Please note I would like these metrics on the client side ( application side ). Also I would prefer open-source libraries/products than anything that requires a paid license.

Thanks

Comment: Except RAC statistics all others are more system related than Oracle related. There isn't any cache in Oracle related to RAC. All instances use regular buffer cache and SQL areas. Ownership is based on object hashes so there is never more than three nodes involved when one instance requires exclusive access to a resource in RAC (owner, requester and the one that uses the resource at the moment).

Comment: Thanks @Husqvik. I'll try other ways to get the system metrics.

Comment: Oracle provides detailed information about memory usage, disk usage, utilization and waits but it relates only to Oracle instance, not system as whole.

Comment: @Husqvik - how/where does Oracle provide this instance specific information ?

Comment: There is many many dynamic performance views in data dictionary, you can start with `GV$PGASTAT, GV$SGASTAT, GV$MEMORY_DYNAMIC_COMPONENTS;
SELECT * FROM GV$SYSSTAT JOIN GV$STATNAME ON GV$SYSSTAT.STATISTIC# = GV$STATNAME.STATISTIC#; same query with GV$SESSTAT; GV$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY` Everything starting GV$ contains data from all instances in RAC. V$ the instance you are connected to. SESSSTAT and SYSSTAT are incremental so to get reasonable values you always need to view difference between two moments in time to see what happened. SQL*Plus uses it for showing AUTOTRACE information.

Comment: @Husqvik - thank you. I will use these queries.